# jQuery: modal form doesn't submit on enter click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that my modal form would submit on `enter` click. I've checked all of the solutions in here, but none of these helped.

I'm trying to solve it like this:

```
    $('#field-id').keypress(function(e)) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#modal-form-submit').submit();
}
```

Now it's not submitting. when I use `alert` inside if, it shows the alert.

`#modal-form-submit` - is the button id, which has to be clicked when I click enter. What's wrong here?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't submit the button, you need to submit the form.
Assuming that your form has `id="modal-form"`, this should work

```
$('#modal-form').submit();
```

Or you [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the button:

```
$('#modal-form-submit').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Hm, none of these works. First one I think doesn't work because it cannot see the form in my modal. There are no `form` tags inside of it, just `divs`. But why the trigger could not work? I use `button-id` which I want to trigger..

`$('#button-id-to-trigger).trigger('click');`

Comment: You can't submit a value without a form... You might want to add your HTML to the question...

Answer (score 1):

> `#modal-form-submit` - is the button id

*Buttons* don't submit, *forms* do.  Submit the form:

```
$('#modal-form-submit').closest('form').submit();
```